# CLI Data loader export with dynamic file name

Tags: apex, data-loader, data

I would like to export the account data periodically using CLI data loader and generate the export file names dynamically with export time stamps.Eg:- If i am running the export @28-Mar-2016 , file should be "AccountExport28-Mar-2016" .Any idea how to do this

Comment: Did you find solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

The [SETTING UP DATA LOADER 9.0 FOR AUTO PROCESSES](http://www.developerforce.com/media/Cheatsheet_Setting_Up_Automated_Data_Loader_9_0.pdf) cheatsheet has an entry key that will help here:

> **Parameter**
>
> <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="C:\Program
>   Files\salesforce.com\Apex Data Loader 9.0\test\ extract.csv" />
>
> **Description:**
>
> Signifies the location and file name of
>   the dataaccess type process.
>   If running a csvRead, the process will
>   look for the file in this location.
>   *If running a csvWrite, **the process will
>   replace the file in this location**.*

There is an example of this in the [dataloader source code](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/blob/0fcc4001c2c977686ee0f8b569cb4da0b7db158c/src/main/resources/templates/process-conf.xml#L86).

You will need to update the `dataAccess.name` entry in the process-conf.xml with the required output format.

Answer (score 3):

The output file name is set with the dataAccess.name property which **can** be set dynamically in the command line.

From https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader README

> The command-line version runs with whatever properties you have in your config.properties file, but you can also pass paramters at runtime as arguments to the program.
>
> For example, the following command sets the operation to insert regardless of what settings are contained in the config.properties file:

```
java -cp target/dataloader-xx.0-uber.jar -Dsalesforce.config.dir=CONFIG_DIR com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner process.operation=insert
```

I would recommend extending (or creating another) process.bat file to support these parameters, instead of hard-coding it in process.bat. To do so, open process.bat and find this line

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -cp ..\dataloader-42.0.0-uber.jar -Dsalesforce.config.dir=%1 com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner %PROCESS_OPTION%
```

and add %3% at the end like this

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -cp ..\dataloader-42.0.0-uber.jar -Dsalesforce.config.dir=%1 com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner %PROCESS_OPTION% %3%
```

Then when running process.bat add the parameter(s) in quotes

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin\"
process.bat ../myconfigdir AccountExport "dataAccess.name=C:\OutputDir\output %mydate%_%mytime%.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated my RunExport.bat to contain:

cd "c:\SalesForce\Dataloader\bin"

process.bat c:\SalesForce\DataExports caseExport "dataAccess.name=c:\Salesforce\DataExports\extracts\caseExport_%Date:/= % %Time::=.%.csv"

This results in a new .csv created with the timestamp appended