# data loader cli

Tags: data-loader

How can we give a dynamic name to the exported file through Data loader CLI.
Currently the exported file is getting overridden whenever I run the .bat file and its name is hard-coded which I have given in my xml file , but I want the name to be dynamic for example it can say "fileName + today's date" .

So , is it possible not to overwrite the file downloaded and create a new file every time and also , have the name of the file appended by today's date .

Comment: Jitesh, please search to see if an existing question exists for what you want to ask and upvote that rather than ask it again as it does not help to have lots of duplicates here making it harder to find topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This recent [question and answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/115760/cli-data-loader-export-with-dynamic-file-name) should deal with this on a dynamic file name for Data loader.